# MySQL Trigger Variables error when sorting

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the next code that cannot solve.

The line Set @Numero=... Returns error

```
  Begin
Declare @Numero INT;
SET @Numero= SELECT id from visita where cliente_id=OLD.cliente_Id order by id desc limit 1;


INSERT INTO HistoricoMaquina
    SET
    Precio=OLD.Precio,
    fecha = NOW(),
    Visita_Id=@Numero;
End;
```

I have tried

```
select @Numero=Id from visita where cliente_id=1 order by id desc limit 1;
```

Also

```
select @Numero=Id from visita where cliente_id=1 order by id desc limit 1;
```

But none of them works, Any Idea?

Comment: Enclose select in brackets ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if your Select query gives an answer

```
INSERT INTO HistoricoMaquina (Precio,fecha,Visita_Id) 
 SELECT OLD.Precio, NOw(),id from visita where cliente_id=OLD.cliente_Id order by id desc limit 1;
```